# For what are used the first 2 bytes in a java String

Tags: java, string

I send a string from java server to a C Client. In the client there are always 2 extra Bytes at the beginning of the String. I guess java use them to indicate the size of the string ?

I send the string with this code 
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF(randomString);

Comment: How do you send it?

Comment: By any chance, do you send the string by calling `writeUTF`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending the string to the server by calling `writeUTF`, the wire format does indeed include the length of the string sent as a `short` in the first two bytes:

> Writes a string to the specified DataOutput using modified UTF-8 encoding in a machine-independent manner. **First, two bytes are written to out as if by the `writeShort` method giving the number of bytes to follow**. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string.  (emphasis added)

You can look up the specifics of going on in the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#DataOutputStream.writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, the java doc tells us:

> Writes a string to the specified DataOutput using modified UTF-8
>   encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> First, two bytes are written to out as if by the writeShort method
>   giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of
>         bytes actually written out, not the length of the string.

[Click for the source code on GrepCode.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#324)

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)  of UTF-8, I think.